# Remove non-latin1 characters from string in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, encoding, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have a string that may contain russian or other non-latin 1 symbols that have to be removed from that string. Exact name of the encoding used is "iso-8859-1". I could loop through all of the symbols in the string but in such case, how can I get the list of latin-1 characters? Don't think finding a list of hex codes of latin-1 symbols on the web and hardcoding them would be a good solution.